# How to use shared_preferences in provider on flutter....?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, provider

I created an project using Provide. After, for saving changes on my app, I tried  to use shared_preferences plugin. But I cant't use it...!

How can I do..?

Comment: Can you add some code to your question so we can understand what happened?

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this:

```
sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        sharedPrefs.setString('youVariableName', Provider.of<YourModel>(context, listen: false).youVariableName);
```

of course write this when you have value in Provider variable.